# next.js + GraphQL: "Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option...."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, next.js, apollo

There are numerous threads about this problem everywhere online, but no solutions are working for me.

I am getting the error:

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an , or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.

Here is a basic version of my code:

```
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  useQuery,
  gql,
} from "@apollo/client";


export default function Home() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: MY_URL,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  const PRODUCTS = gql`
    query {
      products(pageSize: 20, currentPage: 1, filter: {}) {
        items {
          id
          name
        }
        total_count
      }
    }
  `;

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(PRODUCTS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Head>
          <title>Create Next App</title>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>

        <main className={styles.main}>
          <a>Escolher: </a>
          <br></br>
          {data.products.map(({ id, name }) => (
            <li key={id}>
                <a>{name}</a>
              <br />
            </li>
          ))}
        </main>
      </div>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

These are the only dependencies that I have on my package.json (I don't think the problem is here, but just to be sure):

```
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.13",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "next": "10.0.9",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.35",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  }
```

My JS code works fine with hardcoded data and the GraphQL query is also valid. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The issue is you are using useQuery before the component is rendered with your ApolloProvider component. You need to define your client in Home's parent component or use useQuery in a child component rather than in Home.

Answer (score -1):

By following this tutorial I was able to move on from this error:

https://www.apollographql.com/blog/building-a-next-js-app-with-apollo-client-slash-graphql/

Ignore the backend part if you don't need it, that's what I did.